# Button click is not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
<form class="cityForm form-horizontal form-label-right" action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="city col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="city">City<span class="required">*</span> </label>
                <div class="">
                    <select class="form-control" id="city" name="pick_up_city">
                        <option>Select City</option>
                        <option>Mumbai</option>
                        <option>Delhi</option>
                        <option>Jaipur</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="address col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="address">Address<span class="required">*</span> </label>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="pick_up_address"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="multiCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="multiCheck">Have more than one pickup point?
            <br> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group hide" id="cityFormExtend">
        <div class="city col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="city">City<span class="required">*</span> </label>
                <div class="">
                    <select class="form-control" id="city" name="pick_up_city">
                        <option>Select City</option>
                        <option>Mumbai</option>
                        <option>Delhi</option>
                        <option>Jaipur</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="address col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="address">Address<span class="required">*</span> </label>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="pick_up_address"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="multiBtn">
            <button type="button" class="addBtn">Add another pickup location</button>
            <button type="button" class="removeBtn">Remove this pickup location</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The above is my html form and it has got two form-group classes. The first one is always displayed as the browser opens and the second one appears only when the checkbox is checked. It is working fine up to here.

Now, I want the `removeBtn` to remove the new form created and `addBtn` to add another form.

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#multiCheck').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            var $pick = $('#cityFormExtend');
            $clone = $pick.clone().removeClass('hide').removeAttr('id').insertBefore($pick);
        }
        if (!this.checked) {
            $clone.remove();
        }
    }).on('click', '.addBtn', function() {
        var $pick = $(this).parents('.form-group');
        $clone = $pick.clone().insertBefore($pick);
    }).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
        var $pick = $(this).parents('.form-group');
        $pick.remove();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
 <script>
 $(document).on('click', '.addBtn', function(){
        var $pick = $(this).parents('.form-group');
        $clone = $pick.clone().insertBefore($pick);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
        var $pick = $(this).parents('.form-group');
        $pick.remove();
    });
</script>
```